# Clear cells in multiple sheets from SSIS by VBA

Tags: vba, ssis, automation

How I can use below VBA coding in SSIS vba. I want to clear cells(data) from multiple sheets from SSIS by VBA coding

```
sub cod()

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Case management details").Range("A2:K10000").clear
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("interface Timeliness").Range("A2:G20000").clear
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Life Events").Range("A2:N10000").clear

End sub
```

Comment: What is your issue exactly. Why couldn't you achieve what you want? What went wrong? • your question is very unclear.

Comment: I get fresh data every month, which I need to load in dashboard, to automate it I have created data flow task in SSIS. But this automation only transfers the data from excel source to my macro enabled excel dashboard. Now I want to create script task which will delete old data from sheets(mentioned in question) before loading the new data. So I want to know how I can put above VBA code in script task which can work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem here. If you decided to solve this using SSIS component try with `Script Task`.
After you create excel steps will be:

1. Add `Script Task` on control flow.
2. Double click on component.
3. Press 'Edit Script...' button.
4. Right-click on the project in new visual studio windows (should be something like 'ST_' and some guid) and click on `Manage NuGet Packages...`
5. From 'Browse' tab install:

   - Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
   - Microsoft.CSharp
6. Into namespaces region add these 2 lines:

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder;
```

7. Copy below code into `ScriptMain` class:

```
var appExcel = new Excel.Application();
string filename = @"D:\PathToExcel\ExcelFile.xlsx";

var newBook = appExcel.Workbooks.Open(filename);
var oSheet1 = newBook.Worksheets["Case management details"];
oSheet1.Range("A2", "K10000").Delete();

newBook.Save();
appExcel.Workbooks.Close();
appExcel.Quit();
```

8. Close without saving the second visual studio window (where you write script code).
9. Run the package

**Note:**

Instead of hardcoded file location, you can replace it with a package variable. In this case 2nd line will be:

```
string filename = Dts.Variables["User::ExcelFilePath"].Value.ToString();
```

I tested this package before write answer and everything work perfect!

With this logic, create multiple sheet instance and delete what you want.
If something isn't clear or non-logical write me in a comment and I will make correction.

Comment: Thank you so much Marko. I am going to try it today :)

Comment: Hello Marko, I just tried it. I followed every step( I used microsoft C# as script lan). 1) I right clicked on ST, installed, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel and Microsoft.CSharp   .. 2) in name spaces region I added, using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;, using Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder, Here i was able to see using system data and other things which I did not touch I just added above things as you advised. 3)I copy pasted above coding in public void Main(), and updated the file path but it is still giving this error:-  Error at Script Task: The binary code for the script is not found

Comment: I tried debugging and I think it is hitting error at new Excel.Application(). It is showing 'Excel' could not be found (are you using missing a using directive or an assembly reference)

Comment: Hey Marko, thank you so so much for your help. It is working now, I tried to debug and I changed small things in code and it is working now but still please do let me know if you have any concern.   In name space:- I tried using Microsoft.Office.Interop only( removed Excel) and modified first line of code (var appExcel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application() )  , and it worked.

Comment: @YugalSharma i know that error: "The binary code for the script is not found". It occurs because SSIS is 'wild' tool and not work so great with C# in it. The only way to fix this in future is to try variant just like you tried with namespaces and recreating script component with same code. Regards.